# PHP date timezone bug

Tags: php, apache

First of all here is my php.ini configuration regarding date:

```
 [Date]
 date.timezone = 'America/Sao_Paulo'
```

When i get ini_get('date.timezone') it fives me the following America/Sao_paulo **(Notice the lowercase P)**

I have the following error everytime i use `date()`

> It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are
>   *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those
>   methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Sao_Paulo'
>   for 'BRT/-3.0/no DST'

If i use

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
```

Everything goes fine so i guess something is screwing my timezone configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are setting it in the correct php.ini?

Call phpinfo() and make sure you are modifying the ini file listed under "Loaded Configuration File"

Edit: While you are looking at phpinfo() you can also see if the timezone is actually being set by looking under Date->Default timezone

Comment: Yes i checked it before, the loaded configuration file is /etc/php.ini , The values on timezone are  Timezone Database=internal,Default timezone=America/Sao_Paulo. And the error above also shows on phpinfo